# WPF control-template: why specify a Grid with no ColumnDefinations/RowDefinations as the outter element?

Tags: wpf, grid, controltemplate

I've been reading Programming WPF, here is one of the examples about Control Template:

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="addButton" Content="Add">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Width="128" Height="32" Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" />
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

I'm wondering why use a grid but not a simpler panel such as canvas? Since we didn't decalre any row/columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify any rows or columns, one of each is implicit, therefore giving you a single grid cell. Thus, both the `Ellipse` and `ContentPresenter` occupy the same grid cell. The z-order of items added to the same cell is determined by the order in which they are added. In this case, the `ContentPresenter` will appear "on top of" the `Ellipse`.

Were you to to use a `Canvas` instead of a `Grid`, the size of the children would not be restricted by the size of the container. That's because a `Canvas` does not impose any size restraints on its children like the `Grid` does. Therefore, you'd have to specify a size for both the `Ellipse` and `ContentPresenter`, and you'd need to know the size of the `Canvas` to set that size. Ergo, it's just a whole lot easier and more intuitive using a `Grid`.